# Trying to order column from highest frequency count to lowest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've tried the cast and the over partition commented out code at the bottom. I want the [DESC] column to be ordered with the highest counts first.

```
--DROP TABLE #REF

SELECT DISTINCT CASE_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,UNIT_ID,REF_SOURCE_ID,[DESC]
--INTO #REF
FROM CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 ON CDCLIENT.REF_SOURCE_ID = CDTBL1.ID
INNER JOIN CDCLSVC ON CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
WHERE TYPE = 'REF'
ORDER BY CAST([DESC],CASE_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,UNIT_ID,REF_SOURCE_ID as                                     
INTEGER) DESC


--SELECT R.*,
--       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CDTBL1.[DESC]) as COUNTS,
--FROM #REF R;
```

Comment: You should add some sample data and expected output. People do not know your schema so it's not very clear what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ORDER BY [DESC] desc, CASE_NUM desc, etc... for each ordering clause you want.

Comment: This groups the desc column but does not order it by the highest counts first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  CASE_NUM ,
        LAST_NAME ,
        FIRST_NAME ,
        UNIT_ID ,
        REF_SOURCE_ID ,
        [DESC]
FROM    ( SELECT    CASE_NUM ,
                    COUNT(CASE_NUM) AS CASE_NUM_Count ,
                    LAST_NAME ,
                    COUNT(LAST_NAME) AS LAST_NAME_Count ,
                    FIRST_NAME ,
                    COUNT(FIRST_NAME) AS FIRST_NAME_Count ,
                    UNIT_ID ,
                    COUNT(UNIT_ID) AS UNIT_ID_Count ,
                    REF_SOURCE_ID ,
                    COUNT(REF_SOURCE_ID) AS REF_SOURCE_ID_Count ,
                    [DESC] ,
                    COUNT([DESC]) AS DESC_Count
--INTO #REF
          FROM      CDCLIENT
                    INNER JOIN CDTBL1 ON CDCLIENT.REF_SOURCE_ID = CDTBL1.ID
                    INNER JOIN CDCLSVC ON CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
          WHERE     TYPE = 'REF'
          GROUP BY  CASE_NUM ,
                    LAST_NAME ,
                    FIRST_NAME ,
                    UNIT_ID ,
                    REF_SOURCE_ID ,
                    [DESC]
        ) AS InnerLoop
ORDER BY InnerLoop.DESC_Count ,
        InnerLoop.CASE_NUM_Count ,
        InnerLoop.LAST_NAME_Count ,
        InnerLoop.FIRST_NAME_Count ,
        InnerLoop.UNIT_ID_Count ,
        InnerLoop.REF_SOURCE_ID_Count DESC;
```

Comment: I tried this. It does not order the [desc] column with the most counts (occurrences) from highest to lowest. For example if [desc] is the name of a hospital I want the the column ordered by what occurs the most.

Comment: I've just changed the ordering of the columns, so that the 'DESC' column is sorted first.